# Vertically center navigation within row - Skeleton Framework

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am having a problem vertically centering my navigation within the skeleton CSS framework, I have tried other suggestions from all over the Internet but to no avail.

I did manage to get it by adding a margin-top to the top of the ul but it was leaving a big white space underneath the navigation which was pushing page elements underneath it down.

```
<header class="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="four columns"><img class="logo" src="img/redonelogo.png"></div>
            <nav>
                <div class="six columns">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.mainNav {
    padding: 1%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.mainNav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.mainNav ul li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

.mainNav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I have tried adding `margin:0 auto;` to the `ul` item and the `li` item but nothing changed.

Comment: Do you mean centered **despite** the logo because otherwise the menu *is* centered.

Comment: The logo is in a different set of columns, the logo is also dictating the height of the container class,  the problem is that yes it is centered but it isn't centering horizontally inside the six columns.  The only way I get it working is by adding a margin-top to it but as I said it adds space under the ul and is pushing the container div down the page.

Comment: I think you mean centering **vertically** then. Right?

Comment: I did yes, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: You should be able to make the `line-height` of the menu the same as the height of logo image...I think that would do it...otheriwse we might have to get really creative and I'm not sure you want that.

Comment: vertically center of what? Do you want vertically center on the logo? Try to make an image which can make us to understand better.

Comment: Vertically centered inside the six columns, I will provide an image if needed.  I will try @Paulie_D suggestion of line-height first.  I don't mind getting creative :).

Comment: Other than the previous - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `padding` to `0px` on your `ul`

```css
.mainNav {
    padding: 1%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.mainNav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
}

.mainNav ul li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

.mainNav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header class="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="four columns"><img class="logo" src="http://ubuntu-tweak.com/media/appcenter/logo/test-drive-logo.png"></div>
            <nav>
                <div class="six columns">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you issue is a result of only using 10 columns (4 + 6) in your row. With Skeleton you need a row to total 12 columns.